# How to get data from form using JS, when the form has been returned from AJAX itself?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here we have a `<div id="content">` and inside it AJAX loads data from the server. We have preloaded JS scripts in the whole file.
Some of the server's AJAX answers are whole forms. That forms have **the same ids**, but different structures. What is needed is to pick the data from freshly baked forms came from the server via AJAX, using JavaScript and create a kinda queryString to send its data again to the server via AJAX itself.
What has been tried:

- I put a code which is getting data from the form on the page using JS. It works great when the form is a static part of the page and i loaded within the initial DOM loading, but, after AJAX re-loading the real DOM is differ than that in the cache, which has been initially loaded with the page.
- I tried to put JS code into the answer from the server with the form. But, it does not work as well. Even simple `alert('Hello!')` does not work.

I am new in AJAX so, please, do not judge me with all the severity.
Thanks!

Comment: Questions about code should ***include the code*** you're using and a precise description of what the desired outcome is and what you observe when you run your code (including any errors in the console).

Comment: @jfriend00 I am NOT looking for a code but for clue or trick of how to do this. I can write code myself. This question is to find the solution (some architecture ideas, plugins to use etc.)

Comment: There's insufficient information in the question to understand what you're really asking for help with.  HTML and code in the question have a way of making questions a lot, lot clearer.

Comment: @jfriend00 To chto ty tut pishesh - polnaja glupost. Tebe by k vrachu obratitsja... Ili knigi chitat, esli ne ponimaesh prostogo yazyka. Esli ty tup, ne stoit eto vsem demonstrirovat...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your issue is picking up only the latest baked forms, you can try the following approach:-

1. In each ajax call of the page, before setting the response content to the desired div, find all objects having class name called 'lastUpdated' (or any other unique class name that you can come up with) and remove all the lastUpdated class associations using the jQuery code
   `$('.lastUpdated').removeClass("lastUpdated");`
2. Now set the response to the desired div and add the class 'lastUpdated' to this div alone.

Thus at any point of time,

```
$('.lastUpdated')
```

will help you *pick the data from freshly baked forms came from the server*